# Unable to locate package monodevelop

Tags: .net, ubuntu, monodevelop

i am unable to install monodevelop i am running it from terminal

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

but it comes out with error

```
unable to locate package monodevelop
```

how to install monodevelop on linux?

Is there any method to install it from ubuntu software center?

Comment: You should perform the first step to add the mono repo to your envrionment, then use the sudo apt-get install monodevelop

Comment: please advice whats the first step @Edgar

Answer (score 9):

1. `sudo apt install apt-transport-https dirmngr`
2. `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF`
3. `echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu vs-bionic main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-vs.list`
4. `sudo apt update`

make sure you copy this command perfectly, in step 3 make sure you copy all command

Comment: Worked for me (March 2024).  if the above doesn't work, check if the official instructions from https://www.monodevelop.com/download/ -

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely install Monodevelop using Git repo.
There are instructions right [here](http://monodevelop.com/download)

Comment: Those instructions say to put into the terminal `sudo apt-get install monodevelop`, which is the exact thing that is not working.

Comment: @RoboticRenaissance follow the instructions in number 1 first, you should add the repo to your packages first

Answer (score 0):

After doing the above:
Use the first answer solve the problem with monodevelop, then use this answer to install MCS.

incase you face any issue try running below command

> `sudo apt-get -f install`

Now, install mcs utility which can compile your C# into exe file

> `sudo apt-get install mcs`

create a c# file. For Example(This is how you name a c# file): "newfile.cs"

Sample code

```
 //This is a c# program that prints out "Hello World"
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Text;

    namespace IncludeHelp
    {
        class Test
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //This is line will print out "Hello World"
                Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

                //This let's us exit the porgram when you press enter 
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

> Save the file as "newfile.cs"
>
> Open terminal and type `mcs newfile.cs`
>
> This will compile the file and turn it into a .exe file
>
> Now type in the terminal the following `mono newfile.cs`

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install mono-complete